# What language can alter a programs volume continuously?

Tags: audio, adjustment

I'm running Windows 7 and I was playing some Frederic Chopin through my speakers and got tired of adjusting the volume to parts of the song that would be pretty quiet.  I was wondering what language would allow me to listen to a program's audio output and adjust it according to it's output volume.

I have programming experience in JAVA but saw that the same question was asked about JAVA and the answer was that it couldn't do that.  So what language would allow me to do such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

Their web site says they have a *Dynamic Range Compressor.*

BTW:  Your post if off topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Does my question not fall under the 'specific programming question' bullet from the topic information page?

Comment: In my opinion,  no it does not.   Although you mention a programing language, your question appears to be about an application: VLC media player.

Comment: Yes but I was planning on coding an application to do it.  I do mention VLC media player but I guess I should edit it and say any media player.